# Is there a word or term for a person who is proudly ignorant? A person who differentiates "Your & You're" and chooses to be grammatically incorrect

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or term for a person who is proudly ignorant? A person who clearly differentiates between "Your" & "You're" and chooses to be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: If they know the difference and choose to be 'wrong' then they're not _ignorant_.

Comment: They are probably eccentric!

Comment: A grammar Luddite?

Comment: How can this be a duplicate if in this question the person **knows** the official approach and **deliberately chooses** another. He is not simply “ignorant” as @KillingTime notes above.